# Xcode 13 - Count not working on NSMutableArray anymore

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I have something like this in my code which worked fine for many years

```
NSMutableArray* DeviceList = [NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Multi-dimensional (n x m) mutable Array filled throughout the code before arriving here:

if ([[DeviceList objectAtIndex:i] count] == 9))
        {
            [DeviceList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
```

I haven't touched the project for a while and now upgraded to Xcode 13 and get the following error:

*Multiple methods named 'count' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes*

The error list on the left pane shows 12 options where *count* has been declared.

So what has changed that the simple

```
someNSUInteger = [[someArray] count];
```

creates an error and what would be a good way to fix it in 100+ instances without casting every instance with (NSMutableArray*)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is that the compiler does not know what the `objectAtIndex:i` is. If any / all of these arrays have a single-element type, you really should have been using a lightweight generic all this time. So take the time and make them all lightweight generics now. If the compiler knows that `deviceList` is an array _of arrays,_ the problem is solved.

Comment: So in this case the problem is the declaration `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`. You know more about what this is an array of, but you are not telling the compiler what you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objectAtIndex returns "id" (objects of any type). Before it used to be permissive, and you were allowed to call any method on such (such as "count").

A better way to write this code would be to declare an intermediate variable:

```
NSArray *deviceRow = [DeviceList objectAtIndex:i];
if ([deviceRow count] == 9) {
```

or if you know the type if the items inside the array, let's say you have strings:

```
NSArray<NSString *> *deviceRow = [DeviceList objectAtIndex:i];
if ([deviceRow count] == 9) {
```

and even better:

```
NSArray<NSString *> *deviceRow = DeviceList[i];
if (deviceRow.count == 9) {
```

Another problem is that there's too many instances of that, and you'd rather not touch it everywhere.

One way to fix most of the 100 occurences is to define a wrapper class for DeviceList instead of using a "naked" NSMutableArray:

```
@interface MyDeviceList
- (nonnull instancetype)init;
- (nullable NSArray *)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
... any other NSMutableArray methods used in the code ...
@end
```

and replace the array instantiation with:

```
MyDeviceList *DeviceList = [MyDeviceList new];
```

Hopefully you have much less instantiations than unsafe usages.

You could also have some helper methods in MyDeviceList like "countAtIndex" if it happens that you need it a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very helpful and much appreciated!